# three use cases into one use case

Tags: uml, use-case

I have one actor (admin), he can perform some actions over other user accounts such as creating the account, editing the account and deleting the account account. Should I do something like this:

```
          -->UseCase:createAccount
         /
    o   /
   -|- /
    | -----> UseCase:DeleteAccount
   / \ \
  Admin \
         \-->UseCase:EditAccount
```

Or should I do a single case?

```
    o   
   -|- 
    | -----> UseCase:ManageAccounts
   / \ 
  Admin
```

I'm asking this question because I feel that is harder to explain the successful case in the use case description if I have three actions in a single use case.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the abstraction to `Manage Accounts` by having it generalize the three use cases.

Like so:

[image: diagram with generalization]

You can refer to the abstract use case where you need things to be in compact form, and refer to the much more precise "sub" use cases where you want to show details.

Comment: in this one I will have to add descriptions to each case like pre and pos conditions or just in manage accounts ? thanks for your time

Comment: I would only add descriptions where they add value.
So if you have a general precondition for all three (login is a good example) then add that to "manage accounts". Anything specific goes to the respective "sub" use case. Similar to how you would deal with inheritance on code level!

Answer (score -1):

Second one is a better option to adopt as far as clean code and modularity is concerned.

Comment: in that case, each option(delete,add,edit) is an  alternative flow ?

Answer (score -1):

I think that in the diagram, the `Admin` actor should interact with the specialized (child) use cases rather than the more abstract (parent) use case.

Furthermore, it is a good practice to show the system boundary using a frame around all the use cases implemented by your system. This is especially helpful when you have more than one external actor.

[image]

[This page](https://www.modernanalyst.com/Careers/InterviewQuestions/tabid/128/ID/365/What-is-use-case-generalization.aspx) is also helpful for understanding the concept of generalization.