# How to document Generalization Use Cases

Tags: uml, generalization

I have a Generalization in my use case diagram. How can I write the specification for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

[three use cases into one use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457604/three-cases-into-one-case)

My comment there was:

> I would only add descriptions where they add value. So if you have a
>   general precondition for all three (login is a good example) then add
>   that to "manage accounts". Anything specific goes to the respective
>   "sub" use case. Similar to how you would deal with inheritance on code
>   level!

That way you'll avoid redundant documentation that you would need to keep in sync and which would be tiring to read.