# How to represent generalization relationships in use case specfications?

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram, generalization

I have use cases like this:
[get from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457604/three-use-cases-into-one-use-case)

[image]

When I showed my teacher this, she had required specifying all use cases and representing generalization in document. She want me to reuse `Manage Account` specfication in `Add Account`, `Delete Account`, `Edit Account`. How to do that ?

Thank you in advanced and I'm sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the diagram, the `Admin` actor should interact with the specialized (child) use cases rather than the more abstract (parent) use case of the generalization relationship.

Furthermore, it is a good practice to show the system boundary using a frame around all the use cases implemented by your system. This is especially helpful when you have more than one actor.

Complementing the use case diagram, you would typically have a [use case specification](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/use-case/what-is-use-case-specification/) describing the actual sequence of operations of each of your use cases. You could use this to show how all the use cases have a common structure (inherited from `Manage Account`).

[This page](https://www.modernanalyst.com/Careers/InterviewQuestions/tabid/128/ID/365/What-is-use-case-generalization.aspx) is also helpful for understanding the concept of generalization.